# Use batch to randomly select input file for ffmpeg

Tags: batch-file, random, ffmpeg

Please help me! I code ffmpeg add mp3 to image but i want to select random file mp3 when add to image creat video. my code:

```
set INPUT=E:\image
set OUTPUT=E:\video
set mp3inseart = $(shuf -n1 -e e:\music\*) 
: encode video 
for %%i in ("%INPUT%\*.jpg") DO ffmpeg -i "%%i" -i $mp3inseart -threads 0 -shortest -preset ultrafast "%output%\%%~ni.mp4"
```

Comment: The randomness will rely on your shell or scripting language. It is not an issue with ffmpeg, so add proper tag of your shell or scripting language. Unrelated to random: You need to loop the image, so use `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "%%i" ...`. Also need `-vf format=yuv420p` and `-movflags +faststart` output options for compatibility.

Comment: I mean need a random input! I want a ffmpeg script that can get a random mp3 file in a specific input directory to run sequentially until all the files in that directory disappear. for %% i in ("% INPUT% *. *") DO ffmpeg -loop 1 -i (random) "%% i.jpg" -i (random) "%% i" -threads 0 -shortest -preset ultrafast "% output%% ~ ni.mp4". Thanks if you can help!

Comment: `ffmpeg` doesn't have a random input feature, but you should be able to do this with your shell or scripting language. So this isn't a `ffmpeg` question. This looks like Windows batch scripting to me so I added that tag.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understood the error in my script. currently it is looping for ffmpeg loop. I want to have one more random variable that is taken in another folder to put it in that for loop. I'm embarrassed to solve it. I want to use the windows command script to put that variable into ffmpeg and I haven't resolved it yet. If you can, please help me put the $ variable (shuf -n1 -e e: music *) so that ffmpeg can understand. Sincere thanks!

Comment: I don't know batch scripting. I tagged it with batch-file thinking that someone who knows that will answer, but they may be intimidated by ffmpeg (which is complex by itself). Perhaps you should edit the question to be specifically about random variables and exclude ffmpeg because this does not seem to be a question about ffmpeg itself.